# Distinct values inside populate in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I am  populating profile field in user collection. Inside profile i want to get distinct values  of the location field. Is it possible to use distinct inside populate? Otherwise how can i achieve the same?

```
User.find({roles:'service_provider'}).select('profile').populate('profile','location').exec(function(err,locations){
  if(err){
        return res.status(400).send({
           message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
       });
  }
    locations = locations.filter(function (doc) {
       return doc.profile;
   });

  res.jsonp({locations:locations});
 });
```

Thanks in advance.